# get a specific row from the html with a specific word using regular expression

Tags: c#, html, regex

I want to fetch all rows having a specific word/string in its.. and store it in array
I have a string as below

```
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>7676</td>
    <td>8767</td>
</tr>
```

**I want to fetch a row having the string Total and the value of  should store in array**

So output should

```
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>567</td>
    </tr>

 <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>7676</td>
        <td>8767</td>
    </tr>
```

what should be the regular expression to fetch a row with a string "Total"

Comment: What regex have you got so far?

Comment: @c24w As i am new to regex i just get the <td> with word total by "<td[^>]*>Total</td>"  but i want whole row.....

Comment: Why don't you use JQuery for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build arrays for each table row that has a cell with the word "Total", you could use this regex:

```
(?<=<tr>\s*<td>Total</td>)(\s*<td>\d+</td>)+(?=\s*</tr>)
```

Which would give you the following 2 matches:

```
<td>123</td>
<td>567</td>
```

and

```
<td>7676</td>
<td>8767</td>
```

On these matches you could then split with this regex to get arrays in return:

```
\D+
```

Answer (score 0):

IN JQUERY UR SOLUTION WILL--->

```
var tbl = $('#tblId')
var array = [];

$('tr td' ,tbl).each(function(){
    var htmlstring = (this).innerHTML;
    if(htmlstring == 'Total')
    {
        if((this).innerHTML == 'Total') 
        {
            $('td', this.parentNode).each(function(){
                array.push(this);
            });
        }
    }
});
alert(array);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gXGj6/13/

Answer (score 0):

Good solution using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/robfarmer/KaGBL/2/

**HTML:**

```
Source
<table id="source">
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>7676</td>
    <td>8767</td>
</tr>
</table>
Results
<table id="results"></table>

Array Results:
<ul id="arrayResults"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#source tr td:contains('Total')").closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#results");

    var cells = [];

    $("#source tr td:contains('Total')").closest("tr")
    .children("td").not(":contains('Total')").each(function(index, element) {
        cells.push($(element).text());
    });

    $(cells).each(function(index, element) {
        $("#arrayResults").append($("<li>").text(element));
    });
});
```